# SharePoint Reminder to whom haven't complete the task

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin

As per title, how can i set the certain amount of days to complete the task and if it is due then 1st **reminder will send out to person which not complete the task**.

In other words:

1.Manager needs to complete the task by 7th in the month.

2.Reminder will be sent out automatically to the manager that hasn't finished the task yet after the due date.

Comment: Have you had a look at retention options? You can specify workflows to run after X days/months/years after a given value in a date column

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is possible through SharePoint designer workflow or through JavaSript. Because there should be a trigger to perform a task, like clicking a button is the trigger and saving the transaction is the task. But in SPD Workflow you may find only three triggers like Item Added event, Item edited event and manual trigger of workflow.

But as per your requirement, it seems to be it should be a scheduled task, so the better option is to go with some timer job kind of approaches. You may get lots of online source for timer jobs. And the best practice is to create a console application with CSOM and attach it with a windows scheduler.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. Looking forward for the timer job.

How can i separate the the person who havent complete the task in order to resend the email again as reminder as my approach.

my case:
in a group contains 3 users, A B and C. 
A have complete the task while B and C havent.
How can i sort the user in that particular group in order to be able to resend the email(Reminder)

Comment: If the answer is helpful mark it as answer

Comment: Where do you store the information that A have completed the task and  B and C doesnt?